# Magento Minicart showing blank

Tags: php, html, css, magento, magento2

Currently i am working on http://flurys.digifrizz.com/catalog/category/view/id/4. I am making a custom theme. But the main problem i faced is that the minicart is empty nothing is shown.

Here is the code for header from where minicart is called

```
<span class="shoppingBag">
    <i class="fa fa-shopping-bag ml-3 font-size24"></i>
</span>

<?php echo $block->getLayout()
    ->createBlock('Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar')
    ->setTemplate('Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml')
    ->toHtml();
?>
```

Please help

Comment: check browser console.

Comment: Please check this page http://flurys.digifrizz.com/catalog/category/view/id/4

Comment: clciking on the minicart just show the box with no data

Comment: you have errors in your browser console. Please fix them first

Comment: Yes but am not sure sometimes the error s are displaying other time no errors

Comment: the element `$('.owl-carousel')` doesn't exist on at least some of the pages. The javascript then dies. Then you get problems (like magento refusing to call it's ajax requests). either add a check (an if() ) into the code or select the proper element in the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try by deploying the static content.
2. Seems like you are overriding the default template wrong. You need to iovverride the minicart default template in your custom theme.
3. Please check: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96540/magento-2-how-to-override-mini-cart-default-template-html-file

Comment: I am not overriding i am just implementing it in custom theme